# Send Multiple Node Json Post in Python

Tags: python, json, google-cloud-messaging

I understand how to send a simple JSON in python.

What I can't find is how to make a more complex JSON object. It doesn't even need to be very complex, I am simply testing out Google Cloud Messaging, and I need to send something that looks like this:

```
{
    "collapse_key" : "Food-Promo",
    "time_to_live" : 3600,
    "delay_while_idle" : "true",
    "data" : {
        "Category" : "FOOD",
        "Type": "VEG",
    }
    "registration_ids": ["APA4lj5jl54l2h..."],
},
```

I have not been able to find a way to do this in Python. Most of my experience is with Java, so maybe that's part of why I can't find this, because it seems it would be simple and I'm worried I've already seen a solution and passed over it.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, exactly what are you having trouble with? What's the difference between a "simple JSON" object and a "more complex" one?

Comment: What doesn't work with `json.dumps()`?

Comment: I am having trouble turning the JSON that I wrote into something I can use with json.dumps. I can use json.dumps with something like : jdata = { "title": title }, json.dumps(title)
But that 'data' object in the middle is giving me trouble.

Comment: I meant jdata = {"title": title}, json.dumps(jdata)

Comment: what version of python are you using?

Comment: Basic overview should be build up your structure in python first, using lists, dicts, whatever, and nesting as desired, and then just json.dumps() it.  In general, you shouldn't be writing raw JSON, but using the languages data structures, and then convert to JSON using internal methods/functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> myDict = {'x' : 1, 'y' : 2}
>>> myList = [1,2,3]
>>> post = {'uname' : 'jon', 'node' : myDict, 'access-levels' : myList}
>>> json.dumps(post)
'{"node": {"y": 2, "x": 1}, "uname": "jon", "access-levels": [1, 2, 3]}'
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

`data` is just a nested dictionary. That is, it's just the same as any other element of the dictionary, except that its value is itself a dictionary.

If you were building up the object line by line (which you would almost certainly never do) you might do something like this:

```
obj = {}

obj["collapse_key"] = "Food-Promo"
obj["time_to_live"] = 3600,
obj["delay_while_idle" : "true",

data = {}
data["Category"] = "FOOD"
data["Type"] = "VEG"

obj["data"] = data

obj["registration_ids"] = ["APA4lj5jl54l2h..."]
```